# How to find location of semantically malformed parameterized type in code. JBoss Weld throws java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException

Tags: java, debugging, generics, jboss-weld, weld

Apparently I have put a malformed parameterized type in my code somewhere, but the location is unknown as my IDE has not generated a warning and the stack trace does not reveal the spot where the error was encountered.  Any suggestions on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated.  I'm stumped.

```
11:04:14,476 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Event] (MSC service thread 1-3) WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.omnifaces.VetoAnnotatedTypeExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.  
11:04:14,479 DEBUG [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) Discovered SYNTHETIC BeanDeploymentArchive (org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-cdi:main.additionalClasses)  
11:04:14,481 DEBUG [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (MSC service thread 1-3) WELD-000106: Bean: Built-in Bean [javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager] with qualifiers [@Default]  
11:04:14,481 DEBUG [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (MSC service thread 1-3) WELD-000106: Bean: Built-in Bean [org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl] with qualifiers [@Default]  
11:04:14,493 DEBUG [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (MSC service thread 1-3) WELD-000106: Bean: Extension [class org.jboss.resteasy.cdi.ResteasyCdiExtension] with qualifiers [@Default]; application.war  
11:04:14,494 DEBUG [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) Discovered SYNTHETIC BeanDeploymentArchive (org.hibernate.validator.cdi:main.additionalClasses)  
11:04:14,495 DEBUG [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (MSC service thread 1-3) WELD-000106: Bean: Built-in Bean [javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager] with qualifiers [@Default]  
11:04:14,495 DEBUG [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (MSC service thread 1-3) WELD-000106: Bean: Built-in Bean [org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl] with qualifiers [@Default]  
11:04:14,504 DEBUG [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (MSC service thread 1-3) WELD-000106: Bean: Extension [class org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.ValidationExtension] with qualifiers [@Default]; application.war  
11:04:14,509 DEBUG [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (MSC service thread 1-3) WELD-000106: Bean: Extension [class com.sun.faces.flow.FlowDiscoveryCDIExtension] with qualifiers [@Default]; application.war  
11:04:14,512 DEBUG [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (MSC service thread 1-3) WELD-000106: Bean: Extension [class com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewScopeExtension] with qualifiers [@Default]; application.war  
11:04:14,513 DEBUG [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) Discovered SYNTHETIC BeanDeploymentArchive (org.jberet.jberet-core:main.additionalClasses)  
11:04:14,514 DEBUG [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (MSC service thread 1-3) WELD-000106: Bean: Built-in Bean [javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager] with qualifiers [@Default]  
11:04:14,514 DEBUG [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (MSC service thread 1-3) WELD-000106: Bean: Built-in Bean [org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl] with qualifiers [@Default]  
11:04:14,516 DEBUG [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (MSC service thread 1-3) WELD-000106: Bean: Extension [class org.jberet.creation.BatchCDIExtension] with qualifiers [@Default]; application.war  
11:04:14,520 DEBUG [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (MSC service thread 1-3) WELD-000106: Bean: Extension [class org.omnifaces.cdi.eager.EagerExtension] with qualifiers [@Default]; application.war  
11:04:14,521 DEBUG [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (MSC service thread 1-3) WELD-000106: Bean: Built-in Bean [javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager] with qualifiers [@Default]  
11:04:14,521 DEBUG [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (MSC service thread 1-3) WELD-000106: Bean: Built-in Bean [org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl] with qualifiers [@Default]  
11:04:15,712 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."application.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."application.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service  
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]  
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]  
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]  
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]  
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException  
    at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.validateConstructorArguments(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:58) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]  
    at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.<init>(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:51) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]  
    at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.make(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:92) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]  
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeParameterizedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:105) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]  
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:140) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]  
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]  
    at sun.reflect.generics.repository.ConstructorRepository.getParameterTypes(ConstructorRepository.java:94) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]  
    at java.lang.reflect.Executable.getGenericParameterTypes(Executable.java:279) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]  
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getGenericParameterTypes(Method.java:268) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]  
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedMethod.initParameters(BackedAnnotatedMethod.java:44)  
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedMethod.initParameters(BackedAnnotatedMethod.java:27)  
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedCallable.<init>(BackedAnnotatedCallable.java:34)  
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedMethod.<init>(BackedAnnotatedMethod.java:38)  
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedMethod.of(BackedAnnotatedMethod.java:32)  
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$BackedAnnotatedMethods.computeValue(BackedAnnotatedType.java:193)  
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$BackedAnnotatedMethods.computeValue(BackedAnnotatedType.java:186)  
    at org.jboss.weld.util.LazyValueHolder.get(LazyValueHolder.java:35)  
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$EagerlyInitializedLazyValueHolder.<init>(BackedAnnotatedType.java:154)  
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$BackedAnnotatedMethods.<init>(BackedAnnotatedType.java:186)  
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$BackedAnnotatedMethods.<init>(BackedAnnotatedType.java:186)  
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType.<init>(BackedAnnotatedType.java:66)  
    at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType.of(BackedAnnotatedType.java:47)  
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformClassToBackedAnnotatedType.load(ClassTransformer.java:83)  
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformClassToBackedAnnotatedType.load(ClassTransformer.java:80)  
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3524)  
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2317)  
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2280)  
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2195)  
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3934)  
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3938)  
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4821)  
    at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.LoadingCacheUtils.getCacheValue(LoadingCacheUtils.java:52)  
    at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.LoadingCacheUtils.getCastCacheValue(LoadingCacheUtils.java:80)  
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getBackedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:175)  
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getBackedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:194)  
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.loadAnnotatedType(BeanDeployer.java:119)  
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClass(BeanDeployer.java:96)  
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$1.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:62)  
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$1.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:60)  
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:60)  
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:53)  
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]  
    ... 3 more  

11:04:15,744 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "application.war")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"application.war\".WeldStartService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"application.war\".WeldStartService: Failed to start service  
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException"}}  
11:04:15,760 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "application.war" was rolled back with the following failure message:   
{"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"application.war\".WeldStartService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"application.war\".WeldStartService: Failed to start service  
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException"}}  
11:04:15,792 DEBUG [org.wildfly.jberet] (MSC service thread 1-7) Removing batch environment; ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.application.war:main" from Service Module Loader  
11:04:15,816 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) JBAS011410: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'application.war#primary'  
11:04:15,817 DEBUG [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) HHH000031: Closing  
11:04:15,817 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) Stop region factory  
11:04:15,817 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) Clear region references  
11:04:15,840 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Infinium' 6.0.2.Final  
11:04:16,177 DEBUG [org.infinispan.interceptors.InterceptorChain] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) Interceptor chain size: 6  
11:04:16,177 DEBUG [org.infinispan.interceptors.InterceptorChain] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) Interceptor chain is:   
    >> org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationContextInterceptor  
    >> org.infinispan.interceptors.CacheMgmtInterceptor  
    >> org.infinispan.interceptors.NotificationInterceptor  
    >> org.infinispan.interceptors.locking.NonTransactionalLockingInterceptor  
    >> org.infinispan.interceptors.EntryWrappingInterceptor  
    >> org.infinispan.interceptors.CallInterceptor  
11:04:16,183 DEBUG [org.infinispan.jmx.JmxUtil] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) Object name jboss.infinispan:type=Cache,name="local-query(local)",manager="hibernate",component=Cache already registered  
11:04:16,184 INFO  [org.infinispan.jmx.CacheJmxRegistration] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) ISPN000031: MBeans were successfully registered to the platform MBean server.  
11:04:16,190 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) JBAS010281: Started local-query cache from hibernate container  
11:04:16,192 DEBUG [org.infinispan.CacheImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) Started cache local-query on null  
11:04:16,200 DEBUG [org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) Implicitly destroying ServiceRegistry on de-registration of all child ServiceRegistries  
11:04:16,200 DEBUG [org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.BootstrapServiceRegistryImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) Implicitly destroying Boot-strap registry on de-registration of all child ServiceRegistries  
11:04:16,201 DEBUG [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryRegistry] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) Remove: name=application.war#primary  
11:04:16,202 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS016009: Stopping weld service for deployment application.war  
11:04:16,297 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) JBAS011410: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'application.war#primary'  
11:04:16,302 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan.subsystem] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) local-query cache configuration stopped  
11:04:16,301 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan.subsystem] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 22) timestamps cache configuration stopped  
11:04:16,302 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan.subsystem] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 24) entity cache configuration stopped  
11:04:16,303 DEBUG [org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager] (MSC service thread 1-4) Stopping cache manager ISPN on null  
11:04:16,306 DEBUG [org.infinispan.CacheImpl] (MSC service thread 1-4) Stopping cache local-query on null  
11:04:16,309 DEBUG [org.infinispan.transaction.TransactionTable] (MSC service thread 1-4) Wait for on-going transactions to finish for 30 seconds.  
11:04:16,310 DEBUG [org.infinispan.transaction.TransactionTable] (MSC service thread 1-4) All transactions terminated  
11:04:16,311 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010282: Stopped local-query cache from hibernate container  
11:04:16,317 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan.subsystem] (MSC service thread 1-4) hibernate cache container stopped  
11:04:16,330 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment application.war (runtime-name: application.war) in 555ms
```

UPDATE:

The MalformedParameterizedTypeException is

> "Thrown when a semantically malformed parameterized type is encountered by a reflective method that needs to instantiate it. For example, if the number of type arguments to a parameterized type is wrong."

Comment: Check in your configuration for Infinispan. The stacktrace gives you this hint.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Why Infinispan?  I haven't changed anything in Infinispan.  I think it's something in my code, a generic class doesn't have the correct parameterized type at runtime.  The stack trace doesn't point to a spot in my code to give me a clue as to where the problem is located.  I've updated my question with a reference to the error message associated with the MalformedParameterizedTypeException.

Comment: Oh you're right. I mixed the `ERROR` messages with the Infinispan messages at the bottom of the stacktrace, my bad.

Comment: Because it's happening when Weld does its CDI startup magic it seems as though one of the beans I wrote has a malformed parameterized type.  Because the stack trace gives no indication as to what kind of bean it is or code location I'm not sure quite how to proceed to troubleshoot.  I tried setting logging level to TRACE and that didn't shed any light.  I'm hoping to avoid brute force method of restoring changed source code package-by-package but this seems my only option at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was waaay off.  There was no problem with my code at all.  The problem was that my project had a dependency that was not compatible with a JEE module installed on the server.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>

    <!--
      scope=compile prevents
      Warning:java: Cannot find annotation method 'max()' in type 'javax.validation.constraints.Size':
          class file for javax.validation.constraints.Size not found
    -->
    <scope>compile</scope>

</dependency>
```

The problem started when Intellij (but not Maven) began to issue warnings, such as the one above, when compiling.  The following change eliminated the MalformedParameterizedTypeException problem but reintroduced the annoying Intellij warning.

```
<scope>provided</scope>
```

JetBrains support created a new issue in its bug tracker:  http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-127569